# Rendering a new Component with React Hooks onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to generate a new form when you click a button. I want to do this with hooks. I am struggling to wrap my head around what I need to do, below is an example function and the button. Any help is appreciated.

```
const addStudent = () => {
    console.log("clicked")
    
    return(
        
        <Container>
            <Form form="First Name" type="text" placeholder="First Name"/>
            <Form form="Last Name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name"/>
            <Form form="Date of Birth" type="date"/>
            <Form form="School ID" type="text"/>
            <Form form="Campus" type="text"/>
            <Form form="School Grade" type="text"/>
        </Container>
        

    )
        
    
    console.log(setStudent)
}
```

```
              <button onClick={addStudent}>Add Another Student</button>
```

Comment: You first need to better explain what you want to do.

Comment: I am trying to generate the above components with the given props when a button is clicked. Fairly new to react and dev in general so if I am missing something please let me know.

Comment: @mjconl6291 does the solution below helps you ? i

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-nash-0slhh?file=/src/App.js:97-1145

**App.js**

```
import Input from "./Input";
export default function App() {
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
  const addStudent = () => {
    setStudents(students => [...students, <Input />]);
    console.log("dddd", students);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={addStudent}>Add Another Student</button>
      {students.map((item, i) => (
        <div key={i}>{item}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Input.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Input() {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [lastName, setLastname] = useState("");
  const [Dob, setDob] = useState("");
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "200px", height: "100px", padding: "5px" }}>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={firstName}
        onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="First Name"
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={lastName}
        onChange={e => setLastname(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Last Name"
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={Dob}
        onChange={e => setDob(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="DOB"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think your solution would have worked, although I was able to solve it with useState and creating a variable with the Component.

Comment: @mjconl6291 Can you post your solution, and mark yours as an answer. This will be helpful for other developers who may encounter this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I created a variable called students and using Context for capturing the state values. I then mapped through students and then for the addStudent function just used the spread operator and set setStudents below.

```
const [students, setStudents] = useContext(FormDataContext);

*this is in the return()*

{students.map((student, index) => (
            <FormCard
              key={index}
              index={index}
              handleChange={handleChange}
              student={students[index]}
              metadata={metadata}
            />
          ))}

*then called this function in my button onClick*

const addStudent = () => {
    setStudents([...students, {}]);
  };
```